# Meteor - Using the built-in JavaScript Math library in an Android webview

Tags: meteor

I'm learning to use the Meteor framework and since few days I have this problem.

I want to use some functions of the built-in Math library, like: `Math.trunc()`.

It's work when I launch my program in Chrome or Firefox on Linux or Windows.
It also works on Chrome on Android.

But... It doesn't work when I launch on an Android device using `meteor run meteor-device`.
The application is well installed on my device, I can launch it, but all my variables that use `Math.trunc()` don't appear.
Also I got a message in the console which says that `the object Math doesn't have a trunc function or method`.

Comment: Bellow the exact error message in the console: `(android:http://meteor.local/app/client/js/libFctConvert.js:20) Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Math] has no method 'trunc' `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/trunc) says about `Math.trunc`:

> This is a new technology, part of the ECMAScript 2015 (ES6) standard.
>   This technology's specification has been finalized, but check the
>   compatibility table for usage and implementation status in various
>   browsers.

So your webview is probably just not yet implementing it. Keep in mind that the webview android uses is *not* always the same as the latest chrome you have installed. Probably your best option is to just implement the functionality yourself using `floor` together with an if condition if you really don't want to floor negative values but truncate the decimals instead.

Comment: See http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#Math.trunc - should work in Android 5.1 but not there in 5.0